# Why does session_start() function does not work in php constructor?

Tags: php, oop, session, constructor

This is my below code

first.php

```
class Session
{
   function __construct()
   {
      session_start();
   }
   function start()
   {
      $_SESSION['id'] = "1";
   }
}
```

second.php

```
 require "first.php";
 $session = new Session();
 $session->start();
 echo "Session Id ".$_SESSION['id'];
```

It gives me an error that _SESSION not defined
So i have to define session_start in start function and then it worked but i want to use it in constructor!!

Comment: The error is emitted from which file, `first.php` or the other one?

Comment: Have you written `session_start();` in your second.php?

Comment: the error is emitted from the second.php

Comment: thats what i am calling from the constructor by creating the object of session class @YashMehta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code on my PC (Ubuntu 16.4) and its working fine.

Comment: oops found my mistake!!

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: mistake was in object creation